# Pass object as array of object

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a common method which accepts array of object as parameter.

Now, there are instances where I need to pass just a single object to function call. To save lines of code and memory, I try doing it inline as:

```
func(new ObjectType(param));
```

But this doesn't compile as it is expecting an array of object. How can I transform this object into an array inside my function call? (Does it require another constructor or operator overloading?)

Comment: `new Object[] { object_i_want_in_array }`? Or something like that? Or make an override of the function to take just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the function signature is `func(object[] items)`?

Few options:

- create a new array: `func(new[] { new ObjectType(param) })`
- add a new overload that takes a single parameter: `func(object item)`
- change the signature to [params](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=params%20c%23): `func(params object[] items)`.  This would take an array or an zero of more objects (e.g. `func(item1, item2, item3)`)

Comment: For the first option, I have overridden the default constructor. So I suppose it won't work. 3rd option seems good

Comment: I'm not sure what the constructor has to do with it.  You may have to post some more code to clarify what `func` is and where it's declared.

Comment: There's nothing wrong on having multiple constructor signatures on c#

Comment: @Jcl its not wrong but i suppose it would require me to define a default construct explicitly as well. which I do not want to.

Comment: @Saksham I don't understand what you mean. If you have `Class(object a)` and `Class(object[] a)` you can do `new Class` with either signature. Inside `Class` you can do constructor chaining if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `params` keyword:

```
private void MyFunc(params string[] args)
{
    foreach(string s in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Test it like this

```
MyFunc("foo"); // pass single string
MyFunc(new string[] {"foo", "bar"}); // pass array
```

To be honest, the compiler generates code which creates a new array with a single element if you pass a single string. This shouldn't be a problem, except the function is very performance-critical.